# JSF-2. h:outputFormat. Complex f:param

Tags: jsf-2

How can one parameter output become another parameter input (value)? Or in other words how can i build a complex parameter.

I tried to build parameter.
Here is the code:

```
<h:outputFormat value="Final result is: {0}">
    <f:param>
        <h:outputFormat value="{0} to {1}">
            <f:param value="#{mngr.lowerBound}"/>
            <f:param value="#{mngr.upperBound}"/>
        </h:outputFormat>
    </f:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't using standard JSF functionality. But [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) can do this for you. They implemented a special [`o:param` tag](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param).

For you case, that would be:

```
<h:outputFormat value="Final result is: {0}">
    <o:param>
        <h:outputFormat value="{0} to {1}">
            <f:param value="#{mngr.lowerBound}"/>
            <f:param value="#{mngr.upperBound}"/>
        </h:outputFormat>
    </o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: Does PrimeFaces has anything like o:param?