# Does PrimeFaces has anything like o:param (solution to add complex parameter for outputFormat)?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internationalization, el, omnifaces

The given problem is that passing complex parameter (see code example below) doesn't work in JSF.

```
<h:outputFormat value="Final result is: {0}">
    <f:param>
        <h:outputFormat value="{0} to {1}">
            <f:param value="#{mngr.lowerBound}"/>
            <f:param value="#{mngr.upperBound}"/>
        </h:outputFormat>
    </f:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

I'm **NOT** looking for the solution that uses the ManagedBean, like this:

```
<h:outputFormat value="Final result is: {0}">
    <f:param value="mngr.formattedParams />
</h:outputFormat>
```

However there is a proper solution that works in OmniFaces:
[JSF-2. h:outputFormat. Complex f:param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421624/jsf-2-houtputformat-complex-fparam)

I'm wondering if there is also a solution in PrimeFaces?

Comment: Did the answer help you? Then it is good practice in StackOverflow to 'accept' it.

Comment: Yes it helped, and thx for it. However I always wait 2-4 weeks before I accept the answer finally. Stay calm, I'll accept it if no better one arrives soon. Thx again!

Comment: Fair enough, but it might be good to inform the posters about this. Otherwise, without any feedback,  they might be less inclined to answer newer questions

Comment: OK dude, I'll do it next time ;) Thx for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No PrimeFaces does not have this. There is no reason to either since OmniFaces has it.  And they both target different aspects of JSF: ui component suite vs utility suite so fully complementary